# SPARQL query mixes up different statement nodes for Q-item

Tags: sparql, wikidata, qlever

Edit: Please read the comments to this post - the post itself is answered.

---

The relevant part of my query (retrieving Nobel Prize winners who, at the time of winning, were head of state or head of government) is this:

```
?nobel_laureate p:P39 ?p39 .   # p39 = "position held"
?p39 ps:P39 ?status .
?p39 pq:P580 ?start_time .
OPTIONAL { ?p39 pq:P582 ?end_time . }
...
FILTER ( ?point_in_time >= ?start_time && ?point_in_time <= ?end_time )
```

- `?nobel_laureate` holds Nobel Prize winners.
- `?status holds` the values for the properties "office held by head of state" and "office held by head of government" for the country the Nobel Prize winner is a citizen of
- `?point_in_time` is the time of winning the Nobel Prize.

I now want to retrieve the "start time" and "end time" qualifier values for the "position held" statements with value in `?status`, e.g., "Prime Minister of Sweden" and "Monarch of Sweden" for Hjalmar Branting, who was a Swedish citizen.

He was Prime Minister of Sweden twice.
I have the problem that if I want to check if `?point_in_time` is between "start time" and "end time", the different Prime Minister of Sweden statements get mixed up.

What can I do to keep them apart?

[Full query](https://qlever.cs.uni-freiburg.de/wikidata/YIWRHr)

I did not try anything because I am clueless.

Edit: There a several other people from [this Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_heads_of_state_and_government_Nobel_laureates#In_office) which don't show up in the output for reasons I can't find. Barack Obama and Abiy Ahmed are eliminated by the `FILTER`: For Mikhail Gorbachev and F.W. de Klerk, I don't know why they are missing.

Comment: It seems the exact date for the Nobel Prize, i.e., `?point_in_time` is 1921-01-01. The first term of Hjalmar Branting ended on 27 October 1920 and the second term started on 13 October 1921 according to https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q53620. So he was indeed not Prime Minister of Sweden when he received the Nobel Prize.

Comment: Wow, you're right. Thanks so much! 

It seems that the Wikipedia list just uses the year. I adapted my query to do the same and now Branting is included.
Using YEAR() also helped include Obama because his ?point_in_time was "2009", thus considered before the start of his presidency.
Now I am just clueless how I can include Abiy Ahmed Ali with missing ?end_time_year.
I also still don't get what's up with Gorbachev and de Klerk missing. In their cases, it's not the FILTER's fault.

Comment: I got Gorbachev and de Klerk included by using p/ps rather than wdt for some statements.

Now I just can't include Ali. If someone can help with this, this would be great!

Comment: I just made a detailed post about this problem but then - checking the links which might answer my question - I closed it by accident and now I can't bring myself to write the post again. I should mention that the engine I use currently does not support the BOUND() function.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the Abiy Ahmed Ali issue: the filter does not succeed if `?end_time` is not bound by the `OPTIONAL` clause, because then the `<=` comparison results in an error.

SPARQL has the `bound()` function for this, which checks if the argument is bound or not. In this case something like (untested):

```
FILTER ( year(?point_in_time) >= year(?start_time) && (year(?point_in_time) <= year(?end_time) || ! bound(?end_time) ) )
```

However, QLever does not implement this, so you will get the error:

```
Invalid SPARQL query: Built-in function "bound" not yet implemented
```

An alternative is to use `COALESCE`. This function takes `n` arguments and returns the result of the first expression that does not trigger an error. So you can check the end date condition, if there is an end date it will produce true or false as required, if there is no end date you go to the second argument, which you need to choose such that it always evaluates to true (since somebody who is still in office qualifies for the list if the start date condition is met).

Code:

```
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX pq: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/qualifier/>
PREFIX ps: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?nobel_laureate_name ?nobel_prize_name ?country_name ?status_name ?year
WHERE
  { { ?country wdt:P31/(wdt:P279)* wd:Q6256 . } UNION { ?country wdt:P31/(wdt:P279)* wd:Q7275 . }
   { ?country wdt:P1906 ?status . } UNION { ?country wdt:P1313 ?status . }
   { ?nobel_laureate wdt:P27 ?country . } UNION { ?nobel_laureate wdt:P27/p:P31 ?p31 . 
    ?p31 ps:P31 wd:Q11514315 .
    ?p31 pq:P642 ?country .
 }
    ?nobel_laureate p:P39 ?p39 .
    ?p39 ps:P39 ?status ;
              pq:P580 ?start_time
              OPTIONAL { ?p39 pq:P582 ?end_time . }
    ?nobel_laureate
              p:P166 ?p166 .
    ?p166 ps:P166 ?nobel_prize .
    ?nobel_prize wdt:P361 wd:Q7191 .
    ?p166 pq:P585 ?point_in_time
    FILTER ( year(?point_in_time) >= year(?start_time) && COALESCE ( year(?point_in_time) <= year(?end_time), 1 ) )
    BIND(year(?point_in_time) AS ?year)
    OPTIONAL { ?nobel_laureate wdt:P18 ?image }
    OPTIONAL { ?country wdt:P41 ?flag_image }
    ?nobel_laureate @en@rdfs:label ?nobel_laureate_name .
    ?nobel_prize @en@rdfs:label ?nobel_prize_name .
    ?status @en@rdfs:label ?status_name .
    ?country @en@rdfs:label ?country_name .
  }
ORDER BY ASC(?year)
```

Result (pictures removed to save space):

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, Marijn.
I can't upvote your solution because I don't have enough reputation or something.
Anyway, QLever is under development and constantly gets new functions. The COALESCE function is also just a few weeks old and so far I wasn't familiar with it.